# Display data from DataSet

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtrareport

I want to display data from `DataSet` to my `ReportViewer`. Currently I have 4 reports which contain basic data like `NameSurname`, `NetworkLogin`, `Status`, `OrgUnitID` and I created a filter which will filter this data using `Status` and `OrgUnitID`.

So far here is code

```
public void BindToData()
{
    try
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        string connString = @"Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=DesignSaoOsig1;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        string strproc = "TestReport";
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(strproc, connString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            sda.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = ddlStatus.SelectedValue == "1" ? true : false;
            sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@OrgJed", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ddlOrgUnit.SelectedValue;
            sda.Fill(ds);

            XtraReport report = new XtraReport();

            string nazivIzvjestaja = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(nazivIzvjestaja))
            {
                conn.Close();
            }

            report.DataSource = ds;
            report.DataMember = ds.Tables[0].ToString();

            string[] arrvalues = new string[ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count];

            for (int loopcounter = 0; loopcounter < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; loopcounter++)
            {
                //assign dataset values to array
                arrvalues[loopcounter] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[loopcounter]["PrezimeIme"].ToString();
                arrvalues[loopcounter] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[loopcounter]["NetworkLogin"].ToString();
                arrvalues[loopcounter] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[loopcounter]["Status"].ToString();
                arrvalues[loopcounter] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[loopcounter]["OrgUnitID"].ToString();
                arrvalues[loopcounter] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[loopcounter]["DT_Creat"].ToString();
                arrvalues[loopcounter] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[loopcounter]["DT_Modif"].ToString();                       
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

So far I use `DevExpress`. SO far I catch all data using `for loop` but I have problem and I don't know how to display these data to `Report`.

Any help will be more then welcome.

Comment: You're catching less data in the for loop than you think. Each column is overwriting the last value set in `arrvalues[loopcounter]`, so you're only storing the `DT_Modif` value for each row.

Comment: Hmmm, not sure what do you mean ?

Comment: Since you are not even using `arrvalues` for anything, at least one of your problems is that you are assigning the report DataMember to `ds.Tables[0].ToString();`

Comment: You're not even using arrvalues, so just delete it and all the code referencing it. Take a look at the DevExpress docs for [how to set up an XtraReport's DataSource](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XtraReportBase.DataSource).

Comment: @Crowcoder yes since I store report to DataSet `report.DataSource = ds;`

Comment: I believe the DataMember is the name of a DataTable in the DataSet, not a DataTable ToString()'ed. Look at the value at runtime, it will be the name of the Type, not the name of the table.

Comment: @Crowcoder Sorry ,Where is this line of code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have already said that you have bound the DataSet with the report you can preview the report for checking the result by inserting the following line after loop finished:

```
        report.ShowPreview();
```

I noticed that you are using an untyped dataset for DevExpress it is need to be serialized as it is explained in detail official post of Dev Express: 
[Check for the Official Website blog](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t269524/web-report-designer-how-to-open-a-report-with-an-untyped-dataset-as-a-data-source)

Comment: Try the following: 
DataMember = ds.Tables[0].TableName;

Comment: No, still have problem. Doesnt read report. I get only 'The Document does not contain any pages`